# Bootstrap align image fit box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In the picture below I have a screenshot of my project. Above the red line represents how it is in its current state. Below the red line is what I am trying to achieve. The problem is, I can't get it fullscreen, With that I mean it needs to be filled till the corners. I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I tried a lot of different ways to make this happen but I couldn't get it right and I'm kinda desperate for help right now. This is the image:

[image]

It is build very easily, You can see it in the code below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="page1">
      <div class="list-group">
          <a href="bericht.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <img src="https://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder-800x423.gif" alt="" style="width: 100%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <h6 class="mb-1">Bootstrap element out of alignment</h6>
                  <p class="mb-1" style="font-size: 14px">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas...</p>
                  <small class="float-right text-muted">25 minuten geleden door Henk</small>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h6 class="text-center">Reacties</h6>
                  <p class="text-center">57</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h6 class="text-center">Weergaven</h6>
                  <p class="text-center">2.543</p>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should make your image responsive class="img-fluid"

Comment: along with width=100% and height as auto or to fix it to 100% too

Comment: That doesn't do anything. I tried that already. Thanks for trying to help though :D

Comment: can you try max-width: 100%; instead, don't forget to add classes "img-fluid" too. if you can add a demo with real problem in a codepen or jsfiddle it would be great

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. I added a Code Snippet in the question that you can check out. It clearly shows the problem

Comment: the img is responsive actually if it has ".img-fluid" with max-width: 100% and max-height: 100%. however what you need to achieve as of my understanding that you need to keep the same height as the next div having .col-md-6 .. right?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's `Grid` has default `margin` and `padding` that can be removed by adding the `.no-gutters` class to your `.row`.  Below is an example of how you could achieve this though I've removed your hyperlink entirely as nesting complex structures inside a single hyperlink is well... messy.

```css
.no-gutters {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
}
    
[data-url] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters" data-url="bericht.html">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="https://www.jennybeaumont.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/placeholder-800x423.gif" width="100%" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h6 class="mb-1">Bootstrap element out of alignment</h6>
        <p class="mb-1" style="font-size: 14px">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas...</p>
        <small class="float-right text-muted">25 minuten geleden door Henk</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h6 class="text-center">Reacties</h6>
        <p class="text-center">57</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h6 class="text-center">Weergaven</h6>
        <p class="text-center">2.543</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

The only thing missing at this point is some JavaScript to tie a click event to `data-url`.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I need to have the link otherwise the whole style will be different. It needs to be achieved with the anchor tag. I'm sorry but thanks for helping though